# How can I use strapi in sum query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, strapi

How do I collect the users in the query.

How can I do the following query in strapi?

```
for example :
select sum(users.length) from quizzes
```

[image]

Comment: Where are you trying to "do" this? In Strapi? on the response? Are the users related to the data endpoint you are accessing?

Comment: I am trying to make a strapi

Answer (score 0):

You are getting **the headless API idea** wrong.
If you really need to make database queries inside strapi then
I would strongly recommend you to read [queries part of reference](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/concepts/queries.html#api-reference)

Otherwise:

## Define What do you really need?

Do you need a total sum of user name lengths?
or
Do you need the count of total users?
or
Do you need total users who are registered with a course?

If you are using GraphQL you can get all user id's of

```
query allUsers {
  quizzes() {
    id
    users{
     id
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to count users using GraphQL

https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/guides/count-graphql.html#setup-the-application